# AngularJS: ui-select - keep the value entered if it doesn't result in a match

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to keep the value entered into a ui-select if the value does not match the json feed? I would like to use this to allow a user to create a new applicant but if the applicant already exists, I would like the user to be able to choose the match.

As it is by default, if there is no match, the value is deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see it, you can use the typeahead component of [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I did try typeahead which would be exactly what I need but i kept getting object/object when selected and no values just blanks in the dropdown. After a few days I abandoned typeahead

Comment: @jgravois Do you find a solution ?